# CakePHP 2.4 Auth->login(): Creates an empty record in DB

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I'm upgrading an old CakePHP app to CakePHP 2.4 the login
I got the user model (called Participant) working to login in a user but it also adds a new record in the database (with empty data)

AppController.php

```
// authorization
        $this->Auth->authorize = 'controller';

        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'participants', 'action' => 'login');

        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Participant';
        $this->Auth->userScope = array('Participant.validate_email' => 'yes');
        $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');

        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'welcome');
        $this->Auth->logoutRedirect =  array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'welcome');
        $this->autoRedirect = false;   

        $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'), 
                'userModel' => 'Participant'
            ));
```

ParticipantController.php

```
public function login() {
    if (!(empty($this->data)) && $this->Auth->login()) {
        $this->log('Logged in with success', 'access');
        $this->Participant->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.Participant.id');
        $this->Participant->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM));
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(), null, true);
    }
}
```

Edit1: How do I prevent a new user being created every time someone logs in?

Edit2: Session is has the correct user select also login in with false credentials does not work. Every login triggers a new record to be added in database

Comment: Most likely `id` is empty. Check what exactly `$this->Session->read('Auth.Participant.id')` returns and also consider replacing it with [`AuthComponent::user()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user).

Comment: $this->Session->read('Auth.Participant.id') returned a new id after replacing it with AuthComponent::user('id'); that fixed the problem thanks ndm

Comment: You shouldn't use `!(empty($this->data)` with Cake2.x, but the request object and `is('post')` instead.